# How to compile install percona's mysql build

Tags: linux, mysql

I used to install percona's mysql build by their deb package. However, recently I bought a linode vps and want to do some customizing. Seeking for configure options is failed and can not find useful information from their blog or in tarball package.

Who can help me?

More best practices is appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the instructions on http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/release:start to set up your APT sources (you may have already done this), then do

```
apt-get source mysql-dfsg-5.0
```

to download the source package.  Inside the source package, the configure options are in the file `debian/rules`.  Edit that, and then rebuild (with `dpkg-buildpackage` for example).

Comment: Thanks, and I found the information output by ./configure --help is useful.